# File doesn't start with %PDF-

Tags: asp-classic, pdf-generation, fpdf

I'm having a problem with fpdf files. My page creates a PFD file but in some cases it gives the following error:

[image: error message]

Sorry it's in dutch but that's how it works when you work with clients.
Anyways it says "File doesn't start with %PDF-. Local\EWH-5128-2

The funny thing is that it does work if I work on the site in localhost. Could this be a server setting?

Hope you guys can help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the proper description? Which page, what script? So much typos that I am even unsure are you talking about fpdf, PDF, PDF or something else? What you have tried yourself?

Comment: Is this a plugin for Classic ASP or something that generates from a working folder etc?

Comment: Taken literally, it's telling you that the file it's looking at may not actually be a PDF document. Is "Local\EWH-5128-2" actually a PDF document? If that's supposed to be a filename, I would expect to see ".pdf" or other specifier showing on the end; what's there right now could be interpreted as something else instead (e.g. a file folder path with no specific filename on the end). Thus you're essentially looking at a kind of [PDF] File Not Found error, in effect.

Comment: @acg_so yes, that's what I"ve found. But the case is it does work on my localhost, so I was wondering if it could have anything to do with server setting or anything.

Comment: Have you tried to `Response.Write` your filename to the page? Also, did you use [`Server.MapPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx) to build your filename?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still a bit confused as to what you mean by your description of the failure. When you get the "File doesn't start with" message, can you verify that the application is finding the PDF document you want it to read? Is that file actually in correct PDF form? If you place a known-good PDF document in that location, does the application still fail to read it?

Comment: @acg_so My application creates his own pdf file. Unfortunately I'm on an internship and someone else build the entire application and I have no clue whatsoever where to look to solve this bug. The application is using [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org) to generate the pdf file and I've never before even heard of that. I hoped you guys would be able to know where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was as followed:

In my fpdf.asp a temporary PDF-file was created and then deleted before the program could read it.

```
            xfile=Server.MapPath(lib.fso.GetTempName())
            xf=lib.fopen(xfile,"wb");
            if(xf.number)this.Error("Unable to create output file: " + xfile);
            lib.fwrite(xf,this.buffer);
            lib.fclose(xf);
            outB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            outB.Type = 1
            outB.Open()
            outB.LoadFromFile (xfile)
            Response.BinaryWrite(outB.Read())
            outB.Close()
     //       lib.fso.DeleteFile(xfile);
```

The problem was solved by deleting the line: lib.fso.DeleteFile(xfile);